# Marathon not loading docker container: Failed to get resource statistics for executor

Tags: docker, boot2docker, mesos, mesosphere, marathon

Trying to spin up a docker container using marathon.
I am  using `docker 1.8`, `marathon 0.11`, `mesos 0.23`, `boot2docker`

Here are how my docker images look like and how they are run

> > https://gist.github.com/manishrajkarnikar/3dad3cfb149384d080aa

Here is how my marathon post request look like and the logs from mess master and slave

> > https://gist.github.com/manishrajkarnikar/96d2031e621201d94f7f

**Note** that in the containers started have "executer"  at the end of container name, while mess-slave info log put this warning where it  looks like its searching for container without executor at the end of container name and docker inspect is failing causing status of task failed

```
Failed to get resource statistics for executor 'helloworld.ed922c9d-6ed4-11e5-a8fb-aa13c24df26f' of framework 20151009-222455-1731963072-5050-5-0000: Failed to 'docker inspect mesos-20151009-222455-1731963072-5050-5-S0.79b421f0-2135-437c-b4be-c95dd841ba9a': exit status = exited with status 1 stderr = Error: No such image or container: mesos-20151009-222455-1731963072-5050-5-S0.79b421f0-2135-437c-b4be-c95dd841ba9a
```

This is causing multiple failed containers and all the tasks are getting status of task_failed

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: Can you `docker run dgageot/helloworld ...` locally? That is, is the Docker image successfully pulled and run?

Answer (score 1):

I would have to double check whether this is the exact issue.
But Docker version 1.8 changed the version output (see [MESOS-2986](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MESOS-2986)) which was fixed in [MESOS 0.23.1](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?projectId=12311242&version=12333553). 
Could you check whether 0.23.1 solves that problem?

Thanks!

Comment: I think I even tried 0.24.0 and that even didn't resolve the issue

Comment: It is included in the Patch release 0.24.1 (https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?projectId=12311242&version=12333552). In addition it is included in 0.25.0.

Comment: same issue with 0.24.1. I don't think its the docker version issue, but the container name when executing docker inspect . It looking for 'hello world.XXXX', but i see container which are spun up(then killed soon after) with name 'hello world.XXX.executer'

Comment: here is the link of the result of docker inspect on the failed container https://gist.github.com/manishrajkarnikar/d9e0b7f233bd75e68e9c

Comment: here is conversation in IRC chat https://gist.github.com/manishrajkarnikar/6a48979f4cfaa2d445e7